# Prime factorization (102 digits)

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, factoring

I have a number that consists of 102 digits and I need to factor it. I ran it in alpertrom.com.ar, but it'll take up to 40 hours if I counted all right. Is there any way to make it by hand (stupid question), I mean to simplify computation for the program? Or maybe anyone can factor it out. The professor is probably just testing our processor's computability.

Here's the number: 166045890368446099470756111654736772731460671003059151938763854196360081247044441029824134260263654537

Comment: What was the purpose of the professor's example? If they wanted to make everybody understand that factoring is hard, maybe they have succeeded, because you have not factored it yet, have you? From the context, I suppose the intention was not to test factoring software written by yourself? So, factoring such a number is possible, but it requires software that uses smart enough techniques, and it requires computational power. You can download [Yafu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yafu/) for example; say `factor(1660...37)` to it, and wait. Then you will see the result eventually. Deadline?

Comment: Transforming crypto.SE into factor-a-CTF-modulus-as-a-free-service is a dangerous slope. If there's another question like this consisting mostly of an RSA modulus to factor, I'm thinking of closing it under the rule _"Requests for analyzing ciphertext (..) are off-topic"_, or similar.

Comment: @fgrieu In that case, you'd probably also want to remove this from the HNQs, so it doesn't set an example for other people.

Comment: Well, I did not provide the answer, rather provide the ways to solve it and provide some personal experiences. I considered this as a canonical answer for our site so that any other similar question can be duped on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your 102-digit nuber is two digits more than the first [RSA challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge) [RSA-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA-100) that has 330-bit.

This can be easily achieved with existing libraries like;

- CADO-NFS ; http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/
- NFS factoring: http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/nfs_beginners_guide.html
- Factoring as a service https://seclab.upenn.edu/projects/faas/

  > The Factoring as a Service project is designed to allow anyone to factor 512-bit integers in as little as four hours using the Amazon EC2 platform for less than $100, with minimal setup.

---

**The experiment**

Factor of a 99 digit number
$n =$ 112887987371630998240814603336195913423482111436696007401429072377238341647882152698281999652360869.

1. I have tried with [Pollard's $p$ -1 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm), still running for one and a half-day and did not produce a result, yet. This is what expected due to the [B bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm#How_to_choose_B?) must be around $2^{55}$ with success probability $\dfrac{1}{27}$. I've stopped the experiment after the CADO-NFS succeeds. This is self-implemented Pollard's $p$ -1, one can find an optimized in [GMP-ECM](http://gforge.inria.fr/projects/ecm/)
2. Tried the CADO-NFS. The stable version may not be easily compiled for new machines, so prefer the active one from the [GitLab](https://gitlab.inria.fr/cado-nfs/cado-nfs).

   After ~6 hours with 4 cores, CADO-NFS produced the result. This was an RSA CTF/Challange and I don't want to spoil the fun; here the hash commitments with SHA-512, it is executed with OpenSSL;

   `echo -n "prime x" | openssl sha512`

```
27c64b5b944146aa1e40b35bd09307d04afa8d5fa2a93df9c5e13dc19ab032980ad6d564ab23bfe9484f64c4c43a993c09360f62f6d70a5759dfeabf59f18386

faebc6b3645d45f76c1944c6bd0c51f4e0d276ca750b6b5bc82c162e1e9364e01aab42a85245658d0053af526ba718ec006774b7084235d166e93015fac7733d
```

---

**Experiments on RSA challenges with 6 cores using CADO-NFS**

| RSA Challange | Bit size | Time in minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RSA-100 | 330 | 270 |
| RSA-110 | 364 | 280 |
| RSA-120 | 397 | 1049 |
| RSA-129 | 426 | 3279 |
| RSA-140 | 430 | Not tested |

[image]
The core count is very important to reduce the time as 512-bit can be broken as 4 hours in the EC2 platform.

---

**Details of the experiment**

- CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
- RAM : 32GB - doesn't require much ram, at least during polynomial selection and Sieveing.
- Dedicated cores : 4
- Test machine Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- CUDA - NO
- gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
- cmake version 3.16.3
- external libraries: Nothing out of Ubuntu's canonicals
- CODA-NFS version : GitLab develepment version cloned at 23-01-2021
- The bit sizes;

  - $n$ has 326 bits
  - $p$ has 165 bits
  - $q$ has 162 bits

The `cado-nfs-2.3.0` did not compile and giving errors about HWLOC-  `HWLOC_TOPOLOGY_FLAG_IO_DEVICES`. Asked a friend to test the compile and it worked for them. It was an older Linux version. So I decided to use the [GitLab version](https://gitlab.inria.fr/cado-nfs/cado-nfs).

---

- **Note:** this question did not factor the OPs original number.
- **Historical note:** [RSA-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-100) challenge has 330 bits and broken by Lenstra in 1991.

Comment: how are the minutes/seconds calculated? doesn't seem like a factor of 60

Comment: did you try with ggnfs or msieve? it's been years since I messed around with those programs so idk if they are still used.

Comment: @qwr CADO-NFS output `93645.9/16232.1`. I've used my system real-time measured with time command. No, I did not try ggnfs or msieve.

Comment: 270 minutes is not 32720 seconds, and 3279 minutes is definitely not 7838 seconds. Only after puzzling about this for a long time and starting this comment did it occur to me that you might be using the comma as a decimal separator. In which case you should probably remove the milliseconds, which have no imaginable importance on day-long timescales, rather than baffling many readers.

Comment: @NickMatteo One should read it like 270m32720s. Removed the seconds.

Comment: @kelalaka thank you, but I couldn't run it on my laptop.

Comment: @bheadr73 why did it failed? Were you able to run it?

Comment: @kelalaka I'm not exactly sure what to do after zip file download. IDE I use is codeblocks(c++). I tried to link it but it does nothing,

Comment: @bheadr73 prefers Ubuntu It is easy to install and use. You can run in on virtual machine, too.

Comment: I just installed cado-nfs and the times given are total cpu/real time, not minutes and seconds.

Comment: My Thinkpad P51 laptop took 20 minutes to factor the 99 digit number in this post, which is weird because it has the exact same CPU as the one listed.

Comment: @qwr yes, should I indicate that? This is the real output for 100 `real    270m32,720s
user    64m10,477s
sys     1m19,451s`. I did not interrupt or use the heavy processes to slow them. that is why I've given 6 cores, not 8. How many cores did you use? I've 2.8GHz CPU and core speed important, too.

Answer (score 3):

Using for example [cado-nfs](https://gitlab.inria.fr/cado-nfs/cado-nfs), you can find the factorization (~5min using 32 cores) as
51700365364366863879483895851106199085813538441759 *
3211696652397139991266469757475273013994441374637143

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography and here we are not HW solvers, and this is not out community's way. My answer doesn't provide the solution, rather concentrate on the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: @FelixZimmermann how much ram did it used?