# Paillier estimate attack costs on short keys

Tags: cryptanalysis, homomorphic-encryption

I was thinking about how to use the homeomorphic property of that cryptosystem to achieve not a "semantic security" but a less ambitous obfuscation of the source code (an ipotetical scenario in which a third party execute the obfuscated code, and get a still obfuscated result).
So i was asking myself how much computation time to break a small keysize? i am sure there is a way to calculate "resistance" per bit but i don't know how.

Comment: "[homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)" is a thing, but only distantly related to [homomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism). There's a wide gap between obfuscating code in a way allowing it's execution, and what Paillier encryption achieves. Thus the goal is not clear. Is it asked the estimated cost of breaking Paillier encryption?

Comment: @fgrieu yes my question is about that. i just added a bit of context on the why i would use short (and thus weak) keys. To rephrase the question i would ask : how much it cost, to break a 64bit keypair? and a 128bit? and so on (till 256 or so because above then seems to me too costly for what i am thinking about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as we know, the most efficient attack against well-implemented [Paillier encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) is to factor the public modulus $n$ part of the public key. That's also the best known attack against RSA, thus is well-studied.

For history of factorization open records, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/555). In 2020, [CADO-NFS](https://gitlab.inria.fr/cado-nfs) has [factored](https://caramba.loria.fr/rsa250.txt) a 828-bit $n$ with "roughly 2700 core-years, using Intel Xeon Gold 6130 CPUs as a reference (2.1GHz)".

A [smaller data point](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89560/555): CADO-NFS factors a 337 bit $n$ in 5 mn on a single 32-core system.

---

> How much does it cost to break a 64bit keypair? And a 128bit? And so on till 256 or so?

Nothing worth consideration if there is a single such problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and explanation. So seems that under 512bit it's so simple that does not constitute even a small barier valuable for obfuscation