# CTF question with hint "Quadratic method to solve ifp problem"

Tags: factoring, rabin-cryptosystem

I totally have no idea about this Rabin decrypt problem.
source code:

https://github.com/shanzhuer/myctf/blob/main/crypto/rabin.py

Inside there were $2^{21}$ times of encryption and decryption of Rabin-cryptosystem, with 126 bytes plaintext, 1024-bit public key $N$(unknown 512-bit $p$ and $q$ when $p*q=N$)

the output log is $\dfrac{140}{2^{21}}$ decrypt failure because $2$ small root of ciphertext(less than 126 bytes) exists

and the hint is "Quadratic method to solve if p problem"

I was trying several days to find out how to use the Quadratic method to factor $N$ in this question but didn't work

Can anyone help?

Comment: @kodlu https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1106/18298 Well, you might [not spoil the flag with a hash commitment as I did](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89563/18298)

Comment: i think there is probably some kind of relationship between ciphertext has 2 small roots and factors of N. but i tried many times and didn't work out. if the program print out the values of 2 small roots then i can calculate p from gcd(root1-root2,N). but the program only print out one of the two small roots.

Comment: @shanzhuer did you read about the Quadratic Sieve as a factorization method? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve)

Comment: @ddddavidee yes i did but it's very hard to find out two different x!=y when x^2=y^2 mod n in this question

Comment: @shanzhuer, try to understand *why* the decryption failed. The Rabin cryptosystem maps 4 plaintexts into the same ciphertext. So when you decrypt and fine the 4 square roots, you need to decide which one is the correct to keep. If you have two different square roots... can you do something?

Comment: @ddddavidee i already know gcd(root1-root2,N) is factor for N. but now i just have one of the two small roots. so sad

Comment: Could you please link to the original CTF?

Comment: @ddddavidee it's just an internal competition and only one anonymous team solves.