# How could a 1024‒bits RSA modulus be most economically factored within months today?

Tags: rsa, signature, factoring

Of course this is a question with an answer that is due to evolve.

A 2002 paper about [TWIRL](https://cs-people.bu.edu/tromer/twirl/) stated that the cost would be around 10M\$ and an other 10M\$ to manufacture the device. A later 2007 [paper](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/tanja/SHARCS/talks07/sharcs2007_cairn3_3.pdf) claimed to have improved the design and created an actual FPGA, though at that time they were still used special bus rather than PCIe.

After that, RSA laboratories stopped their bounties, and research slowed, and **no serious paper later seems to have explored the cost of factoring a 1024‒bits RSA modulus in the last 15 years**.

Even if you can today rent 500,000 PCIe Xilinx on AWS, I’m noticing all the latest records for RSA numbers were performed on pure CPU implementations with the latest 1 being on [CADO-NFS](https://cado-nfs.gitlabpages.inria.fr/). Their creators stated that GPUs wouldn’t be of help in any parts because it would break it’s capacities to abort early on unnecessary cases.

#### Question :

What would be the price to factor something like

```
0xdc4e445b69fe9483216d0fa85492b4656287bfb2fb4da5b65f0b86cc2c073f3ee24a038d3d0e88c78b722b466c5ca1c89792c368ed182a5a13df919cac7fe335173cd04f23769d5ef027290f34a86e8fcab014f1a19d395b0662c5c52424a38796dd6f2394047d716abb6f48cc46abee6e2be3168348b456d5878cbec0b57d0f
```

today in order to forge signatures without considering labor designs costs outside the case of the ASIC ?

And with which setup (pure CPU or FPGA or ASIC) would be the less costly to achieve it if rented ?

###### Disclaimer :

I was just offered a [10% of damage bounty](https://web.archive.org/web/20240219004740/https://etherscan.io/address/0xd1ce90003a10e6dab877890ab1fd96511555e4b3#multichain-portfolio) that I agree to share by a casino should I prove with details the feasibility to break the modulus above in the span of a few months.

Comment: 10% of stolable funds represent 20Ethers worth currently 60,000$ but they state the contrary that it’s 1 ETH. In details, they thought they would still be protected by changing their 1024‑bits ᴠʀꜰ keys/contracts every 4/6 months or so and they will now upgrade their key length. But they will only pay on serious demonstration that attacking them for predicting bets within the given timeframe and for less than ~240Ether would be possible (no need however to actually do it).

Comment: Do you have a source for the "500,000", or/and other brand of FPGAs for rent at AWS or other? I think your question is interesting, and on topic when formulated as e.g. _how could a 1024-bit RSA modulus be most economically factored using existing hardware publicly available for rent_? Again I'm less comfortable with the designated modulus and the bounty aspect, whatever exactly it is; and stating your motivation or putting a disclaimer in the body of the Q is not needed. But so far, nobody voted to close your Q.

Comment: @fgrieu based on an article only available in my language https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_de_FPGA#Les_solutions_du_march%C3%A9.  Of course you d have to stack up several pc like servers, but the true is today fpgas can be rented like gpus at many locations/providers (I recall to had see a 12 fpgas per server). I m also interested in the non publicly available asic case should manufacturing costs with running costs appears to be the cheapest solution. The casino is disputing it** but my point with rental hardware is the cost to use more available fpgas≈cost to use use less fpgas for longer.

Comment: @fgrieu though, there appears to exists reasons about why all the latest/largest records were obtained on cpus only implementations so that fpgas might be a slower and costly case than using gpus.

Comment: Well, I did a small [test a while ago](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89560/18298), however, I did not account the memory. When the $n$ increases the memory requirement is also increased to increase the success. This is why you may not see GPUS and standard FPGAs. I need to test further.

Comment: @kelalaka I personally own a 6Tib or ram computer. With pcie, you can dma the memory of the host. **Their stated reason is parallelism is killing the opportunity to stop continue on a case if it s not needed**. With Fpgas, you might also have a faster per thread operations.